# How can I put a column from excel into a IN function in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a long column in Excel which I want to put in an IN (" " , " " , ...) -function in SQL.
How can I do this, concerning that the " " will be a problem when just copy pasting?

e.g.
These are the first couple of rows of the excel file

[image]

I want to put it in the IN function without stating " " all the time:

IN ( " ", " " , ...)

So how can I put an entire column between quotation marks?

Comment: Just delete the final comma.

Comment: How would that help? @GordonLinoff

Comment: I usually just paste the whole column in a text editor, highlight a newline, find-replace with `","`. Fix the beginning and end and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the specific column from the excel file to your database, as a temp table, and then just put it's name in the IN clause

Comment: I think you can create a temporary table, and populate it. then insert its' name in the IN clause. on PostgreSQL this could work:
`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable (col1 varchar);
COPY TempTable FROM 'path\to\table' WITH (FORMAT csv)`
this essentially creates a table for this session alone, and copies the values from the csv file

Comment: then just write:
`select co1 from TempTable  where 'James' in (col1);` for instance

Answer (score 0):

1. In another column, use the concatenate function of excel and concatenate first ", then the cell containing the value, followed by another " and finally a comma.
2. Then copy this formula all throughout the range of cell values and remove the last comma.

You could then copy this entire column's data as your IN clause.